# Search an item in nested array and return the object if found otherwise return the first available object

Tags: javascript, angular

**Data**

```
let data = [
  {
    "brands": []
  },
  {
    "brands": []
  },
  {
    "brands": [
      {
        "name": "brand1"
      },
      {
        "name": "brand2"
      },
      {
        "name": "brand3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "brands": [
      {
        "name": "brand4"
      },
      {
        "name": "brand5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

if I find brand4 its should return
{ "name": "brand4"}

if I find brandZ (if not available in DATA) then it should return the first available brand
{"name": "brand1"}

Is there a way in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the built in find method on JS arrays, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

I believe something like this would work for your needs.

```js
function findBrand(brand){
  let result;
  let parent = data.find(obj => obj.brands.find(brands => brands.name == brand))
  
  if (parent){
    result = parent.brands.find(brands => brands.name == brand)
  }else{
    result = data.find(obj => obj.brands.length > 0).brands[0]
  }

  return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! it's working for me